# Error when adding class to a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am running into an error I cant figure out, because it works with another form. I am trying to add a class to a form - it looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]), html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
```

but this throws an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tLABEL ..., @post.comments.build]), html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} d...

syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
```

If I delete the html: ... the form works (but looks shitty).

This one works (for some reason):
`<%= form_for @post, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>`

It is probably easy to fix, but since I am new to programming - I just dont get it ;)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you have closing parenthesis `)` at the wrong place for the `form_for` helper.

Please try:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
```

Another option is to add a space after `form_for` so that `([@post, @post.comments.build])` and `html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}` become parameters to `form_for`

```
<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]), html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the options hash (even if it is empty) before the html hash:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]), {}, {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Hey Matt - thanks for the quick answer, but I am afraid that didnt do the trick :(. I have edited the post - maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are really close, but i think this might work:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comments]), :html => {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
```

I got that from this question [Multiple parameters for form_for()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631735/multiple-parameters-for-form-for)

Comment: Thanks TMP for the answer - but both solutions dont work. I added something to the post above - maybe that helps?